# Can we use IN clause in jdbcTemplate update?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot

```
public class Test{
  @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  public void updateData(List<String> rollNbr){
   MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
          parameters.addValue("rollNbr", rollNbr);
    String sql = "UPDATE students set marks=50 where rollNbr IN (:rollNbr)";
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameters);
 }
  }    
}
```

When I am giving call to updateData method with list of roll number I am getting following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [UPDATE students set marks=50 where rollNbr IN (:rollNbr)]; The index 1 is out of range.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:110) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1402) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Is `rollNbr` is string type in databse also ?

Answer (score 3):

NamedParameterJdbcTemplate solved problem

Change:

```
public class Test{
  @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  public void updateData(List<String> rollNbr){
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcNamesTpl = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(this.jdbcTemplate);
   MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
          parameters.addValue("rollNbr", rollNbr);
    String sql = "UPDATE students set marks=50 where rollNbr IN (:rollNbr)";
    jdbcNamesTpl.update(sql, parameters);`
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single string parameter containing a JSON array of scalars.

```
String rollNbrs = "[12,232,1,23,513]";
String sql = "UPDATE students set marks=50 where rollNbr IN (select cast(value as int) from openjson(:rollNbr))";
```